# implicit differentiation with trig

Tags: calculus

Hey I am trying to solve this implicit differentiation problem: $\sin(x+y) = xy$

So far I get $$(1 + y')\cdot\cos(x+y) = y+xy'$$

then I distribute my $\cos(x+y)$ into $1 +y'$ and I get $$y'\cos(x+y) + \cos(x+y) = y+ xy'$$
Can you please help I get stuck after this step

Comment: Your goal is to get all of the $y'$ to one side of the equation so it can be isolated. Can you get all of the $y'$ terms alone on the left-hand side? Then from there, can you factor it out to isolate it further?

Comment: Do you mind helping me solve this equation please

Comment: Here's something that might help: in algebra, would you know how to solve $ax + b = cx + d$, for any constants $a,b,c,d$? If so then you know how to solve this. It's not any more complicated, it just looks different

Comment: As Stephen Donovan is suggesting, treat $y'$ like some variable, say $p$, and rearrange to find $p$.